# lme4 singularity for specific independent factor

Tags: r, lme4

My experiment consists in evaluating two variables y (y1, y2) in offspring from different litters according to a variable x from their mothers. I am running a linear mixed model in R with lme4 the following way: y1 ~ x +(1|mom)  and y2 ~ x +(1|mom)

In the first case, the model runs but in the second I obtain a singularity warning message. The data is quite small (11 litters and 29 offspring) and I understand that singularity may originate from this limited sample. However, I am wondering why this happens in one case and not in the other from the exact same structure?

Please find below the code to reproduce the issue. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
y1=c(0.26903580,0.13365153,-0.41765552,-0.80636189,-0.49945988,-1.00212371,-0.17151876,-0.61706171,-0.14339771,-2.25371738,-1.25717754,1.80143680,-1.03968678,
0.05024469,0.82305674,0.37280972,-0.39462624,0.16851854,-0.79639251,-0.23391974,2.04901986,1.83841657,1.91358574,-0.19369511,0.91614178,0.40747619,
0.01780726,-0.42882124,-0.50558551)

y2=c(2.09592403,0.33716864,-0.85235144,0.12872470,-1.58329485,-0.02413419,-1.49157952,1.39589172,-0.40489178,-0.46881459,-0.52717889,-0.24647439,-0.88570247,
1.10209720,0.50799603,-1.51275803,-0.17421382,0.29270060,0.70680923,-0.34652748,-1.34705839,0.76795278,-0.64390750,-0.78564938,0.68735446,2.02139567,
1.17928216,-0.54663366,0.61787315)

x=c(-0.3802510,-0.3802510,-0.3802510,-0.3802510,2.0006079,2.0006079,2.0006079,2.0006079,0.4383239,0.4383239,0.4383239,0.3318247,-0.1488276,-0.7796731,
-0.7796731,-0.7796731,-0.1179862,-0.1179862,-0.3221202,-0.3221202,0.4910143,0.4910143,0.4910143,-0.1179862,-1.5813074,-1.5813074,-0.9842020,-0.9842020,
-0.9842020)

mom=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","d","e","f","f","f","g","g","h","h","i","i","i","g","j","j","k","k","k")

d = data.frame(y1,y2,x,mom)
summary(lmer(formula = y1~x+(1|mom), data = d)) #Model 1
summary(lmer(formula = y2~x+(1|mom), data = d)) #Model 2
```

Comment: I don't see any code. If a model fit is successful does not only depend on the model structure but also on the data that needs to support the model. So, it's not necessarily surprising that one case works and the other doesn't. However, your model looks quite simple, which makes such issues not very likely. Have you plotted the data? Can you make the data available or at least show a scatter plot of y ~ x colored by mom?

Comment: Also, you mention "specific independent factor" in your question title. Is x a factor variable?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason the code hasn't been copy/paste correctly

Comment: Yes, the data appears to be problematic. `lme` also returns a fit with issues (intercept exact zero): `library(nlme);
summary(lme(y2 ~ x, random = ~ 1 | mom, data = d))`

Comment: `blmer` with default priors returns a fit that looks reasonable: `library(blme); 
summary(blmer(formula = y2~x+(1|mom), data = d))`. Its fit for `y1` is not too different from the fit returned by `lmer`.